# Javascript add 2nd array values together if first values are the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Sorry if the title isn't that clear. This is kind of hard to explain for me, as I'm not that good when it comes to multiple arrays.

I have an array: `[ [21, 1000], [21, 500], [18, 100], [18, 200] ]`

Now I want to get this resulting array: `[ [21, 1500], [18, 300] ]`

How do I go about doing this?

I've tried using 21 and 18 as array **keys**, but this way I couldn't use the array in a `for` loop with `.length` counting. I ended up with a total of 4 arrays to almost get it working.

---

**Edit:**

I want to avoid using the 21 and 18 values as array keys.

I also want to be able to iterate over the resulting array/object, and use the 21 and 18 "keys" as well, to make some further changes to my page.

Thanks already for all the responses!

Comment: You cannot use `for` but you can actually use `.each()` for object.

Comment: Why not store the data as objects in the second array?

Comment: It isn't clear what should happen in a case where an element from "first" is not found in "second", or in a case where there is a pair in "second" but there is no matching element in "first". This could make a number of the answers already given, incorrect.

Comment: The first array seemed to be redundant, so no need to check against another array anymore. Post updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely don't need any `jQuery` for this to get the result array you asked for:

```
var one = [21, 18];
var two = [ [21, 1000], [21, 500], [18, 100], [18, 200] ];
var results = [];

for(var i in one) {
    results[i] = 0;

    for(var x in two)
        if(two[x][0] === one[i])
            results[i] = results[i] + two[x][1];

    results[i] = [one[i], results[i]];
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joeterry/kvYnW/2/)** here

Comment: I went with this solution, as it allows me to iterate over the `results` and use the 21/18 "keys" in my output as well.

Answer (score 6):

How about creating an object :

```
var arr = [ [21, 1000], [21, 500], [18, 100], [18, 200] ];
    obj = {};

for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    obj[arr[i][0]] = (obj[arr[i][0]] || 0) + arr[i][1];
}

// obj now equals {18: 300, 21: 1500} 
// obj[21] equals 1500 etc
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/AF4Tt/)

You could create an array the same way :

```
var arr  = [ [21, 1000], [21, 500], [18, 100], [18, 200] ],
    arr2 = [];

for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    arr2[arr[i][0]] = (arr2[arr[i][0]] || 0) + arr[i][1];
}

// giving you the array [18: 300, 21: 1500]
// where arr2[18] equals 300
```

Comment: @ryan - Not sure I get it, why would'nt that work -> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AF4Tt/1/) ? The order in the array does'nt matter!

Comment: Sorry, I got mixed up cause I was writing something else. The order of the second array doesn't matter, however, he has 2 arrays and he is checking the values in the first against the values in the second. You completely ignore the first array. What I meant by the `if` statement was: what if he has the above array but his first array looks like this `[53, 18]`? It was a lack of dealing with the first array I was getting after.

Comment: @ryan - that was the point of the object. Arrays don't have keys, they only have indices, so creating an object from the values in the second array, it would be trivial to see if the values in the first array are in fact keys in the object, as objects actually have keys.

Comment: @adeneo Could you please explain what the `||` operator does in order to achieve the sum?

Comment: If you look at the behavior of @joeterry's fiddle and you change the 21 to something else then you end up with what I think is the OP's actual goal, which is to only add if the values in the second array of arrays match what's in the first array. Yours will add no matter what the values in the fist array are. I agree with you that using an object would be better because it has keys. But what you or I think about using an object isn't that important if it doesn't actually do what the OP wants. And currently yours doesn't do what the question title asks for.

Comment: @ryan I initially wanted to check the 2nd array against the 1st array. But it isn't really necessary, because I can seem to get my resulting array/object from only the 2nd array.

Comment: @jlmmns if that's the case will you update your question a little, or put in a note about how this helped solve, so others looking for the same info know what worked for you?

Comment: @adeneo per jimmns comment I removed my downvote. just wanted to make sure his problem was actually solved. +1 now for suggesting object.

Comment: @ryan Updated my post, sorry for the hassle.

Comment: And everybodys happy, happy, happy! Feel free to accept the answer if it worked out OK?

Comment: @adeneo How do I map property names to the 21/18 keys, in the object? As I would like to use them as well in my output.

Comment: @adeneo Sorry, see my edit. Your code looks really nice and simple, but I needed to iterate over the resulting array/object and be able to output the 21/18 keys as well, instead of only their sums.

Comment: @jlmmns - You'd do that with a for / in loop, like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/AF4Tt/3/)

Answer (score 0):

in case your values are not in order, you can use this:

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/acturbo/YWaja/

javasript:

```
var array1=    [21, 18];
var array2 =   [ [21, 1000], [21, 500], [18, 100], [18, 200] ];
var result =   [ [0,0], [0,0] ];

for (i=0;i<array1.length;i++){

    result[0,i][0] = array1[i];

    for (j=0;j<array2.length;j++){

        var key = array2[i,j][0];
        var val = array2[i,j][1];

        if (  key == array1[i] ){
            result[0,i][1] += val;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possibility, it is using [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), so you need to have a modern browser or use one of the many "shims"/"polyfills" out there.

Javascript

```
var first = [21, 18],
    second = [
        [21, 1000],
        [21, 500],
        [18, 100],
        [18, 200]
    ],
    store = {};
    result = [];


first.forEach(function (element) {
    second.forEach(function (pair) {
        var value;

        if (pair[0] === element) {
            value = store[element] || 0;
            store[element] = value + pair[1];
        }
    });

    if (typeof store[element] === "number") {
        result.push([element, store[element]]);
    }
});

console.log(result);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/NxsPe/)

Update: here is a solution based on the updated question, this also uses [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to do the conversion from an object to the array format that the OP has requested.

Javascript

```
var first = [
        [21, 1000],
        [21, 500],
        [18, 100],
        [18, 200]
    ],
    store = {};
    result;

first.forEach(function (pair) {
    store[pair[0]] = (store[pair[0]] || 0) + pair[1];
});

result = Object.keys(store).map(function (key) {
    return [parseInt(key, 10), store[key]];
});

console.log(result);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/augwr/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function aggregateResults(indexes, inputArray) {
  var ret = [], tmp;
  for (var i=0; i<indexes.length; i++) {
    tmp = 0;
    for (var j=0; j<inputArray.length; j++) {
      tmp += inputArray[j][0] == indexes[i] ? inputArray[j][1] : 0;
    }
    ret.push([indexes[i], tmp])
  }
  return ret;
}
```